# C macro compilation error (AOSP: external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h)

Tags: android, c, macros, android-source, clearsilver

I have a compile error in C, involving a macro, which is driving me nuts.  It's not my code, but rather part of a widely used library. I'll give you the back story, because I know I'll be asked otherwise.

I am trying to build the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) for Droid v.2.3, on Ubuntu v.16.04, via GNU Make v.3.81.  I am encountering numerous errors, which all relate back to this primary one:

```
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
```

According to this guy on "Ask Ubuntu", he encountered this problem after installing `libswitch-perl`:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/830569/external-clearsilver-util-neo-err-h8869-error-expected-expression-before

That seems like a really weird cause!  I have never have compiled the AOSP before, so I cannot make a comparable claim. For what it's worth, I don't have that installed.

```
dpkg-query: package 'libswitch-perl' is not installed and no information is available
```

Ignoring anything other than the source, let's dive into more details.  Here is the pertinent clearsilver code:

```
#if defined(USE_C99_VARARG_MACROS)
#define nerr_raise(e,f,...) \
   nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
#elif defined(USE_GNUC_VARARG_MACROS)
#define nerr_raise(e,f,a...) \
   nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,##a)
#endif

NEOERR *nerr_raisef (const char *func, const char *file, int lineno,
                     NERR_TYPE error, const char *fmt, ...)
                     ATTRIBUTE_PRINTF(5,6);
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
```

I tired moving the macro definition to after the nerr_raisef function definition, and that had no effect.  I also tried these lines (inserted before the line that's failing), to help find the problem:

```
#define mytest1 __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#define myitest2 __FILE__
#define mytest3 __LINE__
#define mytest4(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define mytest5(e,f) nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f)
#define mytest6(e,f,...) nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f)
#define mytest7(e,f,...) nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
#define mytest8(e,f,...) \
   nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)

#ifdef nerr_raise
x
#endif
```

Nothing goes wrong with those.  Note that `mytest8` macro is exactly the same damn thing, with a different name, and that compiles!  Also, the loose `x` doesn't get included, i.e. nerr_raise was not previously defined.

Here's the entire output I get when running `make`:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=2.3.4
TARGET_PRODUCT=imx53_smd
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=user
TARGET_SIMULATOR=false
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=GRJ22
============================================
build/core/main.mk:303: implicitly installing apns-conf_sdk.xml
find: ‘frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html’: No such file or directory
find: ‘out/target/common/docs/gen’: No such file or directory
find: ‘frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html’: No such file or directory
find: ‘out/target/common/docs/gen’: No such file or directory
find: ‘frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html’: No such file or directory
find: ‘out/target/common/docs/gen’: No such file or directory
find: ‘frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html’: No such file or directory
find: ‘out/target/common/docs/gen’: No such file or directory
find: ‘frameworks/base/frameworks/base/docs/html’: No such file or directory
find: ‘out/target/common/docs/gen’: No such file or directory
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE imx53_smd
host Java: droiddoc (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/droiddoc_intermediates/classes)
host C: libclearsilver-jni <= external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_util.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_files.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/ulocks.c
host C: libneo_util <= external/clearsilver/util/neo_hash.c
In file included from external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c:19:0:
external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c: In function ‘uListInit’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c:64:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to create ULIST: Out of memory");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c:70:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to create ULIST: Out of memory");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c: In function ‘uListPop’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/ulist.c:124:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_OUTOFRANGE, "uListPop: empty list");
            ^
In file included from external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_util.c:6:0:
external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_util.c: In function ‘jni_fileload_cb’:
external/clearsilver/java-jni/../util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_util.c:257:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT,
            ^
external/clearsilver/java-jni/../util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/java-jni/j_neo_util.c:268:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT,
            ^
In file included from external/clearsilver/util/neo_files.c:26:0:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_files.c: In function ‘ne_listdir_fmatch’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_files.c:219:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT, "Invalid call to ne_listdir_fmatch");
            ^
In file included from external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:24:0:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘_alloc_hdf’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:62:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise (NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory for hdf element");
            ^
In file included from external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c:22:0:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c: In function ‘string_appendvf’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c:167:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
       return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, 
              ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c: In function ‘string_array_split’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_str.c:223:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise (NERR_ASSERT, "separator must be at least one character");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘hdf_set_attr’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:409:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT, "Unable to set attribute on none existant node");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘_set_value’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:648:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
       return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory");
              ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:795:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
         return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory");
                ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘hdf_set_valuevf’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:869:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory for format string");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘_copy_attr’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:1028:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
       return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate copy of HDF_ATTR");
              ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:1036:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
       return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate copy of HDF_ATTR");
              ^
In file included from external/clearsilver/util/ulocks.c:22:0:
external/clearsilver/util/ulocks.c: In function ‘fLock’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:102:75: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raise_errnof(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                           ^
external/clearsilver/util/ulocks.c:96:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise_errno’
     return nerr_raise_errno (NERR_LOCK, "File lock failed");
            ^
In file included from external/clearsilver/util/neo_hash.c:18:0:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hash.c: In function ‘ne_hash_init’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hash.c:30:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory for NE_HASH");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hash.c:41:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory for NE_HASHNODES");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘hdf_write_string’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:1342:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     if (*s == NULL) return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate empty string");
                            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hash.c: In function ‘ne_hash_insert’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hash.c:91:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
       return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate NE_HASHNODE");
              ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hash.c: In function ‘_hash_resize’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hash.c:229:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_NOMEM, "Unable to allocate memory to resize NE_HASH");
            ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c: In function ‘hdf_read_file’:
external/clearsilver/util/neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
external/clearsilver/util/neo_hdf.c:1834:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT, "Can't read NULL file");
            ^
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libclearsilver-jni_intermediates/j_neo_util.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libneo_util_intermediates/neo_files.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libneo_util_intermediates/ulist.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libneo_util_intermediates/neo_str.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libneo_util_intermediates/ulocks.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libneo_util_intermediates/neo_hash.o] Error 1
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libneo_util_intermediates/neo_hdf.o] Error 1
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
/bin/bash: jar: command not found
make: *** [out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/droiddoc_intermediates/javalib.jar] Error 127
```

Comment: is that whole error? Usualy g++ will add some more information (notes), ie. about the place where this macro was used. Usually the cause might be missing definition (empty) used in the macro call.

Comment: There are other errors which tie back to this.  I'll post those in case it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Check out the revised post.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems unlikely that the libswitch-perl issue you referenced is related to yours.  It just involves a similar syntactic problem.

Comment: You should consider obtaining the preprocessed source text for an affected file (via `gcc -E`).  Examining the erroneous line should at least tell you *what* is going wrong, which might be helpful in figuring out *why*.

Comment: Have you performed the preliminary [environment-selection and target-choice build steps](https://source.android.com/source/building.html)?  In the shell where you are performing the build?

Comment: I have been through that.  I think that's all set...

Comment: I got over this hurdle largely due to your initial suggestion, John.  Check out my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am now confronting a new error in the AOSP build, and it looks like this is going to be a horrible endless battle unless I solve something more fundamental regarding my environment, configuration or whatever.  I did however solve this particular bug in the following way...

Rather than run the whole AOSP make, I try to compile just one file that is choking on this macro:

```
cd external/clearsilver/util
gcc -I/[my full path...]/external/clearsilver neo_files.c
```

RESULT

```
In file included from neo_files.c:26:0:
neo_files.c: In function ‘ne_listdir_fmatch’:
neo_err.h:88:69: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
    nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,__VA_ARGS__)
                                                                     ^
neo_files.c:219:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘nerr_raise’
     return nerr_raise(NERR_ASSERT, "Invalid call to ne_listdir_fmatch");
```

Then, using John Bollinger's suggestion, I use gcc -E:

```
gcc -E -I/[my full path...]/external/clearsilver neo_files.c
```

TRUNCATED RESULT

```
...
  if (files == 
# 218 "neo_files.c" 3 4
              ((void *)0)
# 218 "neo_files.c"
                  )
    return nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,"neo_files.c",219,NERR_ASSERT,"Invalid call to ne_listdir_fmatch",);

...
```

If you look at the very end of the line that the macro expanded into, you see:

```
... NERR_ASSERT,"Invalid call to ne_listdir_fmatch",);
```

Note the comma at the end of the parameter list!  That's the problem!

The solution? Using `##__VAR_ARGRS_`. In the macro.  The ## prefix removes leading commas for you under such scenarios:

```
nerr_raisef(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,__FILE__,__LINE__,e,f,##__VA_ARGS__)
```

I repeated that for a handful of other macros in that neo_err.h files as well.   Then, not only can I compile that one file, but I can run the make for the whole clearsliver util mod:

```
make
```

RESULT

```
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o neo_err.o -c neo_err.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o neo_files.o -c neo_files.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o neo_misc.o -c neo_misc.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o neo_rand.o -c neo_rand.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o ulist.o -c ulist.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o neo_hdf.o -c neo_hdf.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o neo_str.o -c neo_str.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o neo_date.o -c neo_date.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o wildmat.o -c wildmat.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o neo_hash.o -c neo_hash.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o ulocks.o -c ulocks.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o rcfs.o -c rcfs.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o skiplist.o -c skiplist.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o dict.o -c dict.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o filter.o -c filter.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o neo_net.o -c neo_net.c
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -I..  -fPIC -o neo_server.o -c neo_server.c
ar cr ../libs/libneo_utl.a neo_err.o neo_files.o neo_misc.o neo_rand.o ulist.o neo_hdf.o neo_str.o neo_date.o wildmat.o neo_hash.o ulocks.o rcfs.o skiplist.o dict.o filter.o neo_net.o neo_server.o 
ranlib ../libs/libneo_utl.a
```

Success!

Now, on to the next problem with the AOSP nightmare...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, here's my REAL answer:

https://source.android.com/source/known-issues.html#build-error-with-40x-and-earlier-on-ubuntu-1110

> Building IceCreamSandwich 4.0.x (and older versions) on Ubuntu 11.10
>   and newer fails...Either downgrade to Ubuntu 10.04, or use the master
>   branch, which can be compiled on Ubuntu 11.10 and newer.

I'm using source code that someone else wrote for a dramatically customized AOSP, and just handed over in a giant tarball.  I can't mess with what branch of the repo I'm using. Apparently, I have no option but to setup whole separate OS.

Yuk! (Or something like that...)